# Validate IP address and create a registration attempt

Tags: javascript, beginner, error-handling, authentication, promise

I'm a C++/Python developer attempting to learn JavaScript, but I'm struggling to write clean code.  I've read that async.waterfall and Promises are two ways to flatten the code a bit, but my implementation seems far more inflated than what I've grown accustomed to using Python.  Is there anything that I can do to refactor the below code sample to compact it without failing to handle errors?

**nodejs Implementation:**

```
Authenticator.prototype.register = function(opts) {
  var self = this;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    self.__validateIpAddress(opts.ip)
    .then(function() {
      self.__createRegisterAttempt(opts)
      .then(function(attempt) {
         // ...
      }, function(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    }, function(err) {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
};
```

**Python Implementation:** (for comparison)

```
class Authenticator(object):
    # caller must handle exceptions
    def register(self, opts):
        self.__validateIpAddress(opts['ip'])
        attempt = self.__createRegisterAttempt(opts)
        # ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a new promise when you already have a promise is considered a [Promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).  Instead, you can just use the promise that is already available to you.  This then saves you all the reject handlers because if anywhere in the promise chain, there is a rejection that will propagate back.  So, I think you can just do this:

```
Authenticator.prototype.register = function(opts) {
  var self = this;
  return  self.__validateIpAddress(opts.ip).then(function() {
      self.__createRegisterAttempt(opts).then(function(attempt) {
         // ...
      });
  });
};
```